# how to start one flux after completion of another?

Tags: spring-reactor

how can i start Flux after completion of Flux? Flux doesn't depend on result of Flux.

I thought operation then() should do the work, but it just return mono. So what is the correct operator?

Answer (score 3):

[Flux.thenMany](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#thenMany-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) is the operator that you need

```java
    abstract Flux<Integer> flux1();
    abstract Flux<String> flux2();

    public Flux<String> flux2AfterFlux1(){
        return flux1().thenMany(flux2());
    }
```

Comment: How does this differ from usingWhen()?  When should you choose one over the other?

Comment: using and usingWhen are reactive versions of the try-with-resources construct and more related to ensuring resources are closed even in exception cases. See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling

Answer (score 0):

My reply is late, so you have probably either figured this out, or moved on.  I need to do the same thing, so I seem to have achieved this by using `Flux.usingWhen()`.  I need to obtain IDs from my database that exhibit a certain property.  After retrieving these IDs, then I need to get some information about these IDs.  Normally, a join would work, but I am using MongoDB, and joins are horrible, so it is better to do separate, sequential queries.  So let's say I have a Mongo reactive repository with a method called `Flux<String> findInterestingIds()`.  I have another method in the same repository called `Flux<String> findInterestingInformation(String[] interestingIds)` that I need to feed the IDs found in the call to the previous method.  So this is how I handle it:

```
Mono<List<String>> interestingIdsMono = myRepo.findInterestingIds()
    .collectList();
Flux.usingWhen(interestingIdsMono,
    interestingIds -> myRepo.findInterestingInformation(interestingIds),
    interestingIds -> Flux.empty().doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("Complete"));
```

The cleanup function (third parameter) was something that I don't quite yet understand how to use in a good way, so I just logged completion and I do not need to emit anything extra when the flux completes.

ProjectReactor used to have a compose function that is now called transformDeferred, and I had some hopes for that, but I do not quite see how it would apply in this type of situation.  At any rate, this is my attempt at it, so feel free to show me a better way!

Comment: I find that this approach works when *one* flux is dependent on another.  But if multiple fluxes depend on the completion of another flux, it does not make good sense to subscribe to the same flux (that returns the same data) for each dependent Flux.  So I am still looking into it for that case.  Which is a specific case that I need to solve.